# Does this statement tell how much work was done?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

On a physics test the instructor asked the following question:

> If you do work on an object in twice the usual time, your power output is?

I said that you could not answer the question because I did not know how much work was done.  He countered that it was implicit in the sentence how much work was done. I do not intend to use the answer that I get here to go back at the instructor, I am just curious if I am missing something in that statement that tells me how much work was done.

Comment: 'Twice the usual time' implies that the same amount of work is done, though I'd prefer 'If you do a certain amount of work on an object in twice the usual time ...'.

Comment: Read it like this: If you do the usual amount of work in twice the usual time, what is your power output relative to the usual power output?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *logic*, not English. And it's pretty obvious OP's physics instructor isn't a native speaker anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> I am just curious if I am missing something in that statement that tells me how much work was done.

Based on that statement, you cannot tell how much work was done.

But based on the problem it's somewhat implied that the *amount* of work does not matter, but the ***rate*** of work that matters. The change in rate then will produce a proportional change to the power output.

Answer (score 1):

> If you do work on an object in twice the usual time, your power output is?

Obviously some amount of work has been done.  Let's call that amount *n*.  You are correct that based on the statement given, we cannot say that the value of *n* is 17, or 23, or any other number.

The statement also references "the usual time", which we can call *t*, and says that we did *n* units of work in *2t* units of time.

The question then is, if the equation of power includes both work and time units, how does doubling the time without changing the work affect the power?

(And since Power = Work / Time, if you normally do P = *n* / *t* but today you did P = *n* / *2t*, your power output has been halved.)

Comment: Nothing obvious about it, if the question doesn't say "*some* work".

Comment: The test question could have been better worded, certainly.